# Dependent checkbox, do you think this can be simplified more?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following code which is working, I was wondering if this can simplified more.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TnpNV/8/

```
<form name="cbform">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="one" id="one" /> one<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="two" id="two" /> two
</form>​

<script>
$('#one, #two').click(function(event) {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (checked) {
        $('#one').attr('checked', true);
        $('#two').attr('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#one').attr('checked', false);
        $('#two').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
</script>
```

It's basically a two checkbox that is dependent on each other. Jquery was used to check and uncheck them.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Compact most working DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/U5GfF/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/U5GfF/3/

This is the least line version you can get for your code: i.e.

`this.checked` will return `true` and `false` and rest on click event `prop` will set `checked` property accordingly. `:)`

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
$("#one, #two").click(function() {
    $("input").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

**or**

```
$("#one, #two").click(function() {
    $("#one, #two").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

**or**

```
$("#one, #two").on('click', function() {
    $("#one, #two").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: What happens if you have more than 2 inputs? not only the ones to check, like for example input text, button, etc...

Comment: @OscarJara cool, gimme a situation will make you a demo **see here**: in case of may checkboxes. **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/pJ7jY/ `:)`

Comment: +1 Nice one! 2nd is better but don't mix things, if you are using prop(), it will be better to use ".on('click' function(e){});" and not just ".click(function(e){});" as old jQuery versions cause you are able to use prop(), on(), etc... :-)

Comment: @GregPettit Thank-you, you are legend as well! `:)`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `prop()` method:

```
$('#one, #two').click(function(event) { // or $("input:checkbox")
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#one, #two').prop('checked', true); // or $("input:checkbox")
    } else {
        $('#one, #two').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TnpNV/10/)

Comment: per Oscar's answer, you could swap out `prop` for `attr` if you need to support older versions.

Comment: Yo check out the much lesser version below in my post! :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just 2 lines :-)

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/TnpNV/15/

**For jQuery modern versions:**

```
$('#one, #two').on('click', function(e) {
  var prop = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? true : false;
  $('#one, #two').prop('checked', prop);
});​
```

**For jQuery old versions** *(Because I saw in your jsFiddle that you are using jQuery 1.4.4 version) Also, this code will work in all versions.*

```
$('#one, #two').click(function(e) {
  var prop = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? true : false;
  $('#one, #two').attr('checked', prop);
});
```

​

Comment: I'm not a big fan of ternary operators; there are fewer lines of code but I don't personally feel that makes it "simplified". However, a great and compact solution that recognized prop vs. attr, so it gets an upvote from me anyhow!

Comment: @GregPettit I think is the best way to just simplify as OP said, thanks for your appreciation too :-)